# Are processors more efficient at lower temperatures

Tags: central-processing-unit, hpc

I couldn't find a stackexchange site that's more suited for this question, I apologize. This doesn't necessarily have a lot to do with servers and stability....

I do not have problems with stability and I don't have problems with overheating, but I was wondering if higher temperatures (below any throttling threshold) had any effect on efficiency, or more specifically computing power.
The processor in question runs at 100% load 24/7 and is at about 75°C, fans run at about 65%. Is there any point in cranking up the fans to 100% to drop the temperature down to below 70°C ?
Does it make a difference to the lifespan of the processor at these temperatures ?

Comment: Does it affect the lifespan of the processors.. YES!  At what cost and does the cost offset the shorted life span, that is a matter of HUGE debate.  Hence them (big companies) testing air cooled server farms and learning how to shut down unused resources and throttle instead of cooling things off so much.

Comment: I'd love to see some actual hard data on this, but AFAIK, the processor is rated to run at 100% for the entire length of the warranty period, given suitable cooling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resistance of semiconductor devices decreases with temperature and thus, load currents increase. Current - or more exactly, moving charge carriers -
 wear out a chips traces, which is called [Electromigration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromigration). So yes, an increase in temperature will reduce the lifespan of a chip.

A temperature decrease of 5K would be insignificant for an average use case, but since your machine runs at full load and maximum current 24/7, I think every less Kelvin reduces the risk of latent damage at least through migration.